# Unexpected permission behavior with Shopware v6.5.4.0 and Admin SDK

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

So for my app based on the Shopware 6 app system everything worked fine for v6.5.3.3
However, by updating Shopware to v6.5.4.0, I am suddenly getting a bunch of permission errors, even though my app doesn't need them, since it is not using them.

[image]

I don't even have permissions to access my own entities which I created in my entities.xml:

[image]

This explicitly happens when the [repository service](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/data/repository) of the Admin SDK is used. I did not change anything inside my app, so I guess something in the Shopware core changed. I also took a look at the changelog, however, I couldn't find any change which could cause this issue.

Unfortunately, I don't have any clue where to debug, so for once I added all of these permissions. Next up, it is telling me to also add create and delete permissions:

[image]

So, this is a major stopper for my crud app.

Basically, my app uses custom entites, which reads and writes data via the Admin SDK. Nothing special, therefor I did not attach any code. I am glad for any help. Maybe I am missing something from the changelog. Otherwise I will create an issue.

I am using the latest [Admin SDK Version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk) 3.0.14

---

**EDIT:**

So now I am trying to add the `includes` to my code in order to reduce the payload. First of all my manifest.xml:

```
<permissions>
    <read>language</read>
</permissions>
```

Next up, the code in my app:

```js
async loadLanguages(): Promise<void> {
    this.loading = true;

    try {
        const criteria = new data.Classes.Criteria();
        criteria.addIncludes({
            language: ['id']
        });
        const languages = await this.languageRepository.search(criteria);
        // Not logged
        console.log(languages);
    } catch (err: unknown) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            notification.dispatch({
                title: this.$tc('global.default.error'),
                message: err.message,
                variant: 'error'
            });
        }
    }

    this.loading = false;
}
```

in my understanding this should result in a response with all languages containing just the "id" field without the need of any further permissions. However, this results in the same permission error as before. Surprisingly I am getting a 200 status code response in the network tab like this:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "0189e919e85e70a783c1305f521820d9",
      "type": "language",
      "attributes": {
        "apiAlias": "language_foreign_keys_extension"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8888/api/language/0189e919e85e70a783c1305f521820d9"
      },
      "relationships": [],
      "meta": null
    },
    {
      "id": "2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b",
      "type": "language",
      "attributes": {
        "apiAlias": "language_foreign_keys_extension"
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "http://localhost:8888/api/language/2fbb5fe2e29a4d70aa5854ce7ce3e20b"
      },
      "relationships": [],
      "meta": null
    }
  ],
  "included": [],
  "links": {
    "self": "http://localhost:8888/api/search/language"
  },
  "meta": {
    "totalCountMode": 1,
    "total": 2
  },
  "aggregations": []
}
```

Nevertheless, my catch block intercepts it with the permission error. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77824972/shopware-6-5-7-1-admin-extension-sdk-requires-more-unrelated-permissions-to-cms. Does anyone have an update?

Answer (score 3):

The permission behavior was wrong prior v6.5.4. This was fixed with this version. When you are now loading a entity where the app has no [permissions](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#permissions) for then it will throw this error.

To minimize the needed permissions you could reduce the payload by using `includes` in the Criteria. And for the data you get via https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/data/subscribe you can use the selectors to reduce it only to your needed permissions.

Comment: So I added the `includes` to my code and edited the answer. However, I am still getting the permission error. Is there still something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue affecting Shopware platform...

https://github.com/shopware/platform/commit/4203eaa3adc6c69ae3932e1c106fa6914011877b

...and will most likely be fixed with the upcoming minor release v6.5.4.2